# Using tabularx and xcolor

Tags: color, incompatibility, tabularx

Is `tabularx` compatible with `xcolor`?  I did the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[svgnames,hyperref,]{xcolor} % colors for hyperref
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{1.00\linewidth}{X} \toprule
  a
  \\
  b
  \\
  {\color{red}c} \\
  d
  \\
  e
  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

But "c" is displaced so that it takes two rows.  Changing the column type to `l` fixes it.

Is there an easy fix to making `xcolor` work with `tabularx`?

Comment: Try using `\textcolor{red}{c}` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Columns with column type `p` and `X` that is based on `p` are implented via a `\vtop`, which is a `\vbox`, but aligned to the top baseline. `\color` does not start a paragraph, but it creates a whatsit (`\special`). Because of the vertical mode, it becomes the first element in the `\vtop`. Also the tabular environments add struts, therefore the cells in a row have at least the height of the strut.

You can avoid this by starting a paragraph:

- implicit by `\textcolor{red}{c}` or
- explicit with `\leavemode{\color{red}c}`

Comment: Great, thank you!  It's great that there is a community of people who understand these details, but I wonder if these details are really necessary for good typesetting…