# Changing the text color for a cell does change alignment

Tags: tables, beamer, color

If i color the text of a table cell, the text gets aligned wrong.

### Without color:

[image]

### With color:

[image: Cell text colored]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLL}
            test & test & test & test \\
            test & \color{red}test & test & test \\
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

I want to use it in a way like this:

```
\newcommand{\highlight}{\color{black}\cellcolor{red}}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLL}
    test & test & test & test \\
    test & \highlight test & test & test \\
\end{tabulary}
```

Comment: Use `\textcolor{red}{test}` rather -- it works then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either use \leavevmode or \textcolor

```
\documentclass[10pt, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLL}
            test & test & test & test \\
            test & \leavevmode\color{red}test & \textcolor{red}{test} & test \\
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\leavemode` does what i need. Could you explain what's the problem here and why `\leavemode` does solve it?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171896/using-tabularx-and-xcolor/171903#171903